# jQuery slideshow plugin that can make this on the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

Please advise me a jQuery carousel plugin that can make a carousel like the one on the image. I mean that, when the image item becomes active, it moves into the center and becomes large.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this: http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/

Apparently, this is the original 'cover flow', even Apple has licensed this for iTunes.

I've used this on projects before and even integrated it into Drupal (there is a module for this in Drupal, but it didn't work for my needs).  I was also able to modify the code to fit my clients extended needs.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help.  Don't forget to 'accept' though =)